# An error occurred while saving your picture

Tags: gmail

When I upload picture in my Gmail. It shows this message "An error occurred while saving your picture" and I can't upload my picture. 
This problem started when my Google+ account got suspended for a name issue.
What should I do? I really want to upload picture in my Gmail. 
Please anyone kindly suggest me....

Comment: Maybe there's an ugliness filter :-) Just kidding. However, this (unlike your other two questions to date) isn't really programming related so would be better at one of the sister sites (see bottom of page).

Comment: @paxdiablo  LOL ... Ugliness Filter ....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uploading pictures on drive.google.com then insert it with the button "insert files using drive"? Maybe some days later, your problem will be noting serious.